# For some reason ConnectableObservable stops after emitting 128 items

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to create a ConnectableFlowable that emits several objects every second. The following code emits 128 items, and then just stops. Never emitting data again. I was trying to remove flatMap() call, on ten items are emitted infinitely. Any suggestions?

```java
 private ConnectableFlowable<PlcDataPackage> createConnectablePlcFlowable() {
        return createIntervalPlcFlowable().onBackpressureLatest().publish();
    }

    private Flowable<PlcDataPackage> createIntervalPlcFlowable() {
        return Flowable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .onBackpressureLatest()
                .flatMap((Function<Long, Publisher<PlcDataPackage>>) aLong -> 
                     mDataPackageFlowable);
    }

    private Flowable<PlcDataPackage> createPlcFlowable() {
       return Flwable.create(...,BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
    }

 mDataPackageFlowable = createPlcFlowable();
 mConnectableFlowable = createConnectablePlcFlowable();
 mConnectableFlowable.connect();
```

Subscribe code:

```
 addDisposable(mGetPlcUpdatesChanelUseCase.execute()
                              .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                              .subscribe(plcDto -> Timber.d(String.valueOf(++dataCount)), Timber::e));
```

UseCase code:

```
public class GetPlcUpdatesChanelUseCase extends UseCase<PlcDto, Object> {

    private final PlcRepository mPlcRepository;

    public GetPlcUpdatesChanelUseCase(PlcRepository plcRepository) {
        mPlcRepository = plcRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Flowable<PlcDto> buildFlowable(Optional<Object> optional) {
        return mPlcRepository.getUpdatesChannel();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isParamsRequired() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Repository

```
public final class PlcRepositoryImpl implements PlcRepository {

    private final PlcCore mPlcCore;
    private final PlcInfoTopPlcDtoTransformer mPlcInfoTopPlcDtoTransformer = new PlcInfoTopPlcDtoTransformer();

    public PlcRepositoryImpl(PlcCore plcCore) {
        mPlcCore = plcCore;
    }

    @Override
    public Flowable<PlcDto> getUpdatesChannel() {
        return mPlcCore.getPlcConnectableFlowable()
                .map(mPlcInfoTopPlcDtoTransformer::transform);
    }

    @Override
    public Flowable<Object> setDeviceProfileDto(DeviceProfileDto deviceProfileDto) {
        return mPlcCore.setDeviceProfileDto(deviceProfileDto);
    }
}
```

- [rxJava2 = '2.1.3' and rxAndroid = '2.0.1' ]

Comment: `flatMap` runs at most 128 inner flows at once by default. If they don't stop, `flatMap` won't subscribe to more. Either increase the `maxConcurrency` or rethink your flow.

Comment: @akarnokd I am not sure if i understand you right, so you are saying if i create Flowable as i do, i can invoke it only for 128 times. So to fix it i can recreate flowable each time i need it?

Comment: What is `createPlcFlowable()` and why doesn't it end?

Comment: @akarnokd createPlcFlowable() method is creating a common bus for the data retrieved from the remote device, it should stay alive as long as our app is alive. It reads the device state, data, and used to shut it down in case of emergencies.

Comment: Why are you subscribing to it over and over?

Comment: @akarnokd I have just debuged this code, subscribe is called only once. UseCase is also called once. What do you mean by saying that I am subscribing over and over again?
Also i have added subscribe and UseCase code to the question.